# Change values in MySQL-Table with sql-query, which is depended from values of the table

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT min, max, value FROM table
```

Now I want to check if value is null or 0 and min > 0.
If both is true: value should get min and min should get 0.

Is it possible to do that for all rows in that table via SQL or do I have to do that with php?

**Example:**

```
min     max     value
3       0       null
```

should get

```
min     max     value
0       0       3
```

Comment: UPDATE something SET a_thing = whatever, another_thing = whatever_else WHERE some_criterion = some_value AND (some_other_criterion = some_other_value OR some_other_criterion IS something_else)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like (test this first):

```
update table set value=min
where (value is null or value=0) and min > 0
```